# GPS on iPhone 6 is not accurate or working at all

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

1 week ago my GPS worked very accurately on Google Maps. But now it's very inaccurate, seems like it works using 3g connection.

What steps i did:

1. Restarted phone;
2. Reset network/location privacy settings;
3. turned off then turned on location service;

But none of this helped me. Any advices?

Comment: Was this Google Maps through a web browser or the Google Maps app?

Comment: Google Maps app. Same with Yandex maps / 2gis

Comment: What version of the Maps app?  Google just released a version update in the App Store, the latest is 4.27.58.  Also, when you say it's "inaccurate, seems like it works using 3g connection", do you mean it's responding slowly to location changes?  Is it the same on wifi and cell?

Comment: Responding very slow or not at all. I've tried to turn off wifi and cellular (3g/4g) - same effect. Could be a hardware issue? But i did nothing to the phone... not dropped a single time.

Comment: Location Services uses true GPS if it can 'see the sky', plus WiFi & phone mast triangulation when it can't. If all it can 'see' are phone masts, then the accuracy will be lower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was broken GPS antenna, just replaced it and it worked again.

Comment: What do you mean by replaced the GPS antenna? Did you take it to
Apple or a
Tech store or
What?

Comment: Just went to a custom tech, he replaced it for me.